# Trying to re-render after store update via redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am using redux to store menu data in store.

It works fine, but once I update store via dispatch, the Component is not re-rendering, if I use `this.forceUpadate` it works but I don't want to use it. Is there any solution for this.

**Code**

```
class MenuContents extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();  
    this.state = {
      menu : []
    }    
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    // populate the left menu
    fetch("./services/left-menu.json")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      store.dispatch( addLeftMenu(data))
      this.forceUpdate(); // I dont want to use this
    }).catch(function() {
      console.log("An error occured during fetch operation.");
    });
  }
  render() {
    let storeValue = store.getState();
    const leftMenu = storeValue.leftMenu[0];

    const isMenuLoaded = leftMenu !== undefined && leftMenu !== "";
    let menuContents;
    let menu;

    if(isMenuLoaded) {
        menuContents = leftMenu.map((menuItem, index)=> {

        menu = <li role="presentation" key={index}>
                  <a className="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="accordion" href="#">
                  {menuItem.name}
                  </a>

              </li>;
        return menu;
      }
      );
      menuContents = <ul className="nav nav-pills nav-stacked"> {menuContents} </ul>;
    }
    else {
      menuContents = <Spinner />
    }
    return (<div>{menuContents}</div>);
  }
}

export default MenuContents;
```

Please see the below reducer code.

**reducer/index.js**

```
import { ADD_LEFT_MENU } from "../constants/action-types";

const initialState = {
  leftMenu: []
};
const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_LEFT_MENU:
    return { ...state, leftMenu: [...state.leftMenu, action.payload]};
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
export default rootReducer;
```

Comment: Please share your reducer code here

Comment: @SakhiMansoor please see updated code

Comment: where have you connected your component with redux?

Comment: I havent done that, I just use store, dispatch and subscribe, not sure how to do it with `react-redux`

Comment: You can move allo your fetch function into an redux action it’s more logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think going off of what Sakhi Mansoor said, you want to connect your component to the redux store. Here is an article that I think explains it pretty well:

https://medium.com/mofed/reduxs-mysterious-connect-function-526efe1122e4

Basically react components re-render when their state or props change. Right now you have a component and you have a store. What needs to happen is that you will trigger some action which will return something to be consumed by the reducer. The reducer will update the redux store. Then ideally, the store will update the props of the component which will then trigger the re-render.

I think the thing you are missing is the last part. When you call connect like the way they do in the article, it will connect the store to the component. So whenever certain parts of the store changes, it will update the associated props in the component.

Answer (score 1):

If your fetch call doesn't result in changing props or state of the component, React can't know that your component needs re-rendering. You should connect your component with react-redux. Accessing the redux store directly in the component is not how it's usually done, wouldn't recommend that. Most of the ecosystem is built around connected components.

Answer (score 1):

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

class MenuContents extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();  
    this.state = {
      menu : []
    }    
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    // populate the left menu
    fetch("./services/left-menu.json")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      store.dispatch( addLeftMenu(data))
    }).catch(function() {
      console.log("An error occured during fetch operation.");
    });
  }
  render() {
    let storeValue = store.getState();
    const leftMenu = storeValue.leftMenu[0];

    const isMenuLoaded = leftMenu !== undefined && leftMenu !== "";
    let menuContents;
    let menu;

    if(isMenuLoaded) {
        menuContents = leftMenu.map((menuItem, index)=> {

        menu = <li role="presentation" key={index}>
                  <a className="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="accordion" href="#">
                  {menuItem.name}
                  </a>

              </li>;
        return menu;
      }
      );
      menuContents = <ul className="nav nav-pills nav-stacked"> {menuContents} </ul>;
    }
    else {
      menuContents = <Spinner />
    }
    return (<div>{menuContents}</div>);
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
   leftMenu: state.leftMenu,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
   addLeftMenu: bindActionCreators(addLeftMenu, dispatch),
});


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MenuContents);
```

Comment: Do we need `mapDispatchToProps` here? +1